# Yii 2 Export (Kartik) Menu - How can I make Dropdownlist (Exportcolumns) scrollable?

Tags: widget, yii-extensions, yii2

I'm using Yii2 basic and the extension `kartik\export\ExportMenu`.

How can I  make `Dropdownlist` (Exportcolumns) scrollable? I have so many columns to choose, so it doesn't show me all of them when I'm working with a screen resolution of 100%. Some of them are cut off.

Dropdown columns:

```
<?php
    $gridColumns = [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        ['attribute'=>'Personen ID','value' => 'PID'],
        ['attribute'=>'Titel','value' => 'PTitel'],
        ['attribute'=>'Anrede','value' => 'PAnrede'],
        ['attribute'=>'Vorname','value' => 'PVorname'],
        ['attribute'=>'Nachname','value' => 'PNachname'],
        ['attribute'=>'Private Telefonnummer','value' => 'PTelefon'],
        ['attribute'=>'Private Mobiltelefonnummer','value' => 'PMobil'],
        ['attribute'=>'Privatmail','value' => 'PEmail'],
        ['attribute'=>'Private Webadresse','value' => 'PWebadresse'],

        ['attribute'=>'Firmen ID','value' => 'FID'],
        ['attribute'=>'Firmenname','value' => 'FName'],
        ['attribute'=>'Firmenbezeichnung','value' => 'FNamenszusatz'],
        ['attribute'=>'Ist Zentrale','value' => 'FIstZentrale'],

        ['attribute'=>'Beziehungs ID','value' => 'RID'],
        ['attribute'=>'Kommentar','value' => 'RKommentar'],
        ['attribute'=>'Funktion','value' => 'FUName'],
        ['attribute'=>'Zweitfunktion','value' => 'FUName'],
        ['attribute'=>'Branche','value' => 'BRName'],
        ['attribute'=>'Kategorie','value' => 'KName'],

        ['attribute'=>'Erstellt am','value' => 'RErstelltAm'],
        ['attribute'=>'Erstellt von','value' => 'RErstelltVon'],
        ['attribute'=>'Bearbeitet am','value' => 'RLetzteBearbeitung'],
        ['attribute'=>'Bearbeitet von','value' => 'RLetzterBearbeiter'],

        ['attribute'=>'Adress ID','value' => 'AID'],
        ['attribute'=>'Straße','value' => 'AStrasse'],
        ['attribute'=>'Hausnummer','value' => 'AHausnummer'],
        ['attribute'=>'Adresszusatz','value' => 'AAdresszusatz'],
        ['attribute'=>'PLZ','value' => 'APostleitzahl'],
        ['attribute'=>'Ort','value' => 'AOrt'],
        ['attribute'=>'Land','value' => 'ALand'],
        ['attribute'=>'Bundesland','value' => 'ABundesland'],

        [ 'attribute'=>'Firmentelefon','value' => 'AFirmentelefon'],
        [ 'attribute'=>'Firmen Email','value' => 'AFirmenEmail'],
        [ 'attribute'=>'Webadresse','value' => 'AWebadresse'],

        [ 'attribute'=>'Adresskennung','value' => 'AKennung'],
    ];
```

Export widget in view:
The class attributes in `columnSelectorOptions` and `columnSelectorMenuOptions` don't make any difference.

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([

    'columnBatchToggleSettings'=>['label'=>'Alle Wählen'],

    'dropdownOptions' => 
    [
       'label' => 'Exportieren',
       'class' => 'btn btn-wkm'
    ],

    'columnSelectorOptions'=>
    [
       'label' => 'Exportspalten',
       'class' => 'btn btn-default dropdown-toggle',
       'scrollable'=> true,
    ],

    'columnSelectorMenuOptions' => 
    [
        'class' => 'dropdown-menu scrollable-menu',
        'role'=> 'menu'
    ],

   'dataProvider' => $dataProviderClone,
   'columns' => $gridColumns,

   'exportConfig' =>
    [
       ExportMenu::FORMAT_TEXT => false,
       ExportMenu::FORMAT_HTML => false,
       ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL => false,
       ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => false,

       ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL_X => 
       [
         'label' => 'EXCEL',
       ]
    ],

    'container'=>['class'=>'btn-group pull-left', 'style'=> 'margin: 5px']
]);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :) You just have to add a style attribute to the columnSelectorMenuOptions. Changing the site.css had no impact.

```
    'columnSelectorMenuOptions' => 
        [
            'style'=> 'overflow-y: scroll, height: auto; 
                       max-height: 200px;  overflow-x: hidden;', 
       ]
```